# Reduce Docker Image Size

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which involves me installing a large folder as a project (see dockerfile). Checking "docker history" see that copying the folder costs 900MB and installing costs 1.7GB. Is there any way to reduce this image size?

Dockefile (some steps ignored for simplicity):

```
FROM python:3.5

COPY subproject /app/subproject
WORKDIR /app/subproject
RUN pip install -e .

CMD ['python', 'script.py']
```

**Edit:**
The subproject is a git repository in itself. It is required in order for my main project to run.

The subproject's size on my local disk is around 500MB, with 95% of that due to some tar files inside. It install prerequisite packages numpy, pillow,scikit,dlib.

Comment: Can you share some info about your subproject just to get closer to your issue?

Comment: @Mark, I have added some details regarding the subproject

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the lates Docker version, when you are building your image, as per [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#squash-an-images-layers---squash-experimental) you could use the ***experimental*** flag: ***--squash*** which is indented to reduce your image layers, therefore, make the image smaller.

```
docker build --squash -t test .
```

**NOTE:** You would also have to enable experimental features on the machine on which you intend to build the image.

You can also find some good tips here: https://hackernoon.com/tips-to-reduce-docker-image-sizes-876095da3b34